# Monitoring Counters on IBM AIX Server when Load testing using Visual Studio load Test

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2013, load-testing, aix, performancecounter

I am Load testing an desktop application that has three layers server at IBM AIX Server, Java Web services at middle layer and C# UI at the client layer. I am using Visual studio as I need to load test WebServices and Some APIs.

I also want to monitor the performance counters(processor, memory, io etc) at the IBM AIX Server. Is it possible to do this in Visual Studio load test  ?. Can I specify the AIX Server in the counter sets ?.